# Saving data across sessions-PHP

Tags: javascript, php, session, save

If one wanted to have a review section on there website how do you go about saving the information so that anybody who comes across the site can see the review of the product?

Example:

```
<form method="post" action="postToThisPage.php">
     <input type="text" name="review" id="productreview">
     <input type="submit" id="submitbtn value="Submit Review">
</form>

<h1>Product Review</h1>
<p id="review_2></p>

var button = document.getElementById("submitbtn"),
    review = document.getElementById("productreview").innerHTML;

    button.addEventListener("click",function(){
    var review = document.getElementById("productreview").innerHTML;

   document.getElementByID("review_2").innerHTML = review;
})
```

I would like to be able to save the information that will be put into the  so that if anybody came across the site they could see it. How do I save the information that is posted?

I think the answer lies in PHP but I am still not sure how to go about it.

Comment: You'd need to use a database like MySQL or at least flat files read/write on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Database or save the info to files.

As for how to do that...teaching you how to build a comments/review system from "Hello World" to completion is a bit beyond the scope of any answer I'm going to be typing up on here. But a [tutorial is here](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1677579).

A simple google search for "how to build a PHP review system" reveals many more.